How to change css of current button only while all buttons have same class after ajax success callback with jquery
I show query results in html table and in each row is a button for run update query whit ajax.
i need to change button color after click and success ajax callback.
when I use:
function myFunction() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'action.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'code='+<?php echo $ab["code"]; ?>+'&action3='+value,
    success: function(result) {
        $(this).css('background-color','#f50519');
    }
   })
}

button color not change. if use class or ID in $().css() it work but change all buttons if use class and if use id the script run on first button.
please help me!
I read all related questions in stackoverflow.
I use unique number after all variable and move script before php loop is closed.
its work but applies to last row only.
    foreach($result as $ab=>$v) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php $no = $ab+1; echo $no; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["name"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["code"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["count(ab.id)"];?></td>
                <form id="form<?php echo $no;?>">
                <td><select name="ac3<?php echo $no;?>" id="action3<?php echo $no;?>">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td><button id="bt<?php echo $no;?>" class="btn2" onclick="myFunction()">submit</button></input></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <script>
function myFunction() {
var e<?php echo $no;?> = document.getElementById("action3<?php echo $no;?>");
var value<?php echo $no;?> = e<?php echo $no;?>.value;
var text<?php echo $no;?> = e<?php echo $no;?>.options[e<?php echo $no;?>.selectedIndex].text;
   
$('#form<?php echo $no;?>').submit(function(e<?php echo $no;?>){
    e<?php echo $no;?>.preventDefault();
    
$.ajax({
    url: 'action.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'code='+<?php echo $result[$ab]["code"]; ?>+'&action3='+value<?php echo $no;?>,
    success: function(result) {
                $('#bt<?php echo $no;?>').css('background-color','#f50519');
                }
    })
})
}
</script>


You need to pass a reference to the clicked button. Post code including click handler

I solved the problem in this way:
foreach($result as $ab=>$v) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php $no = $ab+1; echo $no; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["name"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["code"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$ab]["count(ab.id)"];?></td>
                <form id="form<?php echo $no;?>">
                <td><select id="action3<?php echo $no;?>">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td><button id="bt<?php echo $no;?>" class="btn2" onclick="myFunction<?php echo $no;?>()">submit</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <script>
function myFunction<?php echo $no;?>() {
var e = document.getElementById("action3<?php echo $no;?>");
var value = e.value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  $('#form<?php echo $no;?>').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: 'action.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'code='+'<?php echo $result[$ab]["code"]; ?>'+'&action3='+value,
    success: function(result) {
                $('#bt<?php echo $no;?>').css('background-color','#f50519');
                }
    })
})
}
</script>


I assume there should be multiple forms in each row having a button each. So here is the jQuery solution for you if that is the case:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demoform").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this); // USE THIS LINE (ITS FORM VARIABLE)
      $.ajax({          
          type: "post",
          url: URL HERE,
          data: DATA HERE,
          success: function(result){
              form.children("button").addClass('active'); // USE FORM VARIABLE AS ABOVE > CHILDREN
          }
      });
    });
});

(I forgot to mention that you also need to one css line for this:)
form button.active{background-color:red;} /* ANY COLOR */

add above CSS line in your stylesheet file.
Try above! Hope it will help! Thanks!

hi! I tried your suggested method but its not work.
You guessed it right that I have one form in each row. in your code css is not changed and just only first form is submitted.

I forgot to mention CSS code for that! You also had to add some css lines like: button.active{background:red;}. I forgot that! I am sorry! But you can retry if you want to. Simple add one CSS line.
